# Receive a message on a device with GCM

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

Actually I am working on the notifications for an Android app.
My two main source of information are this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) and the android developer web site.

#### Let me quickly describe my app:

- In my app I use `web services` (WS) which work with `POST HTTP` request.
- For the Notification I use the `GCM` system.
- My app uses the 'POST HTTP' request system above to be register on my server.
- Actually my server does exactly the same job as the one in the tutorial (that means to register an account in the database with to **two parameters** and the **register ID** of the device, and send a **message** to the device with GCM)

#### Actually all of these steps work:

1. My app receive successfully gets register ID (`gcm.register(SENDER_ID);` work)
2. My app get **successfully registered** on my server
3. My server receives a successful message when I try to send a message from my device

   `{"multicast_id" : 6276079906208554309 , "success" : 1 , "failure" : 0 , "canonical_ids" : 0 , "results" : [{"message_id" : "0:1374826298092960%978fee92f9fd7ecd"}]}`

### The Problem:

- **I receive nothing on my device**

#### What I did:

#### I try to do two versions of the application:

- First I made an app using a part of the code of the tutorial, but with using the `package com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging` instead of the `com.google.android.gcm` which are deprecated (and used in the tutorial), but I was unable to receive a message, so I try a second version …
- This time I took the entire tutorial and just change the register function on the server to use mine, but like the first app, I receive nothing on my device. (I did this to try to understand how work the reception but it did not help me, and now I will forget this way)

### Where do I need your help:

I need some/more explanation how to receive the message sent by my server.

- My main activity uses the code describe on the android developer web site.
- I create a broadcast class using the code on the android developer web site.
- I don’t create any IntentService or service, maybe it is my error, but according what I read I understood that I don’t need one, like before with the deprecated GCMBaseIntentService

#### To conclude:

- I really will appreciate some help to understand what I need to receive the message on my device, because actually I don’t know where I can found the information I need to be able to use this system.

Thanks.

PS: if you need some part of my code , just ask me.

**EDIT**
my `manifest`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.androidhive.pushnotifications2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications2.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <!-- Register Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications2.cop.RegisterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Main Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications2.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"

            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications2" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>         
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And my GcmBroadcastReceiver (who come from the tutorial)

the WakeLocker is the same as the tutorial too.

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ///
        WakeLocker.acquire(context);
        ///
        System.out.println("TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT");
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else {
            sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
        WakeLocker.release();
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your Android Manifest?

Comment: Please post the `GcmBroadcastReceiver` class you are using.