# Android Device is not receving notification when send data from PHP using REST api?

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

> i received GCM registration token for my device but when i am sending message using REST api from PHP, it shows Success but not receving message on device. php code

```
<?php 
 $data = array( 'message' => 'Hello World! First Message from PHP' );
 $ids = 'device registration token';
 // Send a GCM push
 sendGoogleCloudMessage(  $data, $ids );

function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{
// Insert real GCM API key from Google APIs Console
// https://code.google.com/apis/console/        
$apiKey = 'API Key'; //(server API Key)
// Define URL to GCM endpoint
$url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
// Set GCM post variables (device IDs and push payload)     
$post = array(
                'to'  => $ids,
                'data'              => $data,
                );

// Set CURL request headers (authentication and type)       
$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

// Initialize curl handle       
$ch = curl_init();

// Set URL to GCM endpoint      
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

// Set request method to POST       
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

// Set our custom headers       
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

// Get the response back as string instead of printing it       
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// Set JSON post data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

// Actually send the push   
$result = curl_exec( $ch );

// Error handling
if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}

// Close curl handle
curl_close( $ch );

// Debug GCM response       
echo $result;
print_r($result);
}
?>
```

while submitting PHP file, it returns message as below, it seems message shows 'success' but no message received at device. can someone suggest if i need to take additional step or doing something wrong?

```
{"multicast_id":8550022549195779350,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1459795352923689%21f96bfff9fd7ecd"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that your API key is correct, and that your server IP is listed as trusted by the certificate. Sometimes, WiFi connected devices become unresponsive to GCM after a while. Try to restart your device. It should start receiving all the messages you have sent.

Also, from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430770/android-gcm-message-successfully-sent-but-not-received), check if you mistakenly used `android:permission="com.google.android.gcm.c2dm.permission.SEND"` instead of `android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @abielita, permissions are correct. Issue with parsing of message. So no issue, app is receiving the message.